# How to set the Learning Rate of an optimizer in Flux.jl

Tags: julia, flux.jl

I would like to set the default learning rate for my optimizer in Flux. I was looking at this example: https://fluxml.ai/Flux.jl/stable/training/optimisers/ and it appears that the interface to do so is through the `update!` function. Is this the way to set the Learning rate or are their other options as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Flux.jl docs](https://fluxml.ai/Flux.jl/stable/training/optimisers/), there are a few different interfaces to set the learning rate. For an optimizer, you can use the `update!()` function. In the case of gradient descent:

> Descent(η = 0.1):
> Classic gradient descent optimiser with learning rate η. For each parameter
> p and its gradient δp, this runs p -= η*δp

which means we can pass in some learning rate (usually between 0.1 and 0.001) to the `Descent` function to set the LR.

There are a bunch of other functions you can use to specify the LR for specific optimizer use cases and you can find those here: https://fluxml.ai/Flux.jl/stable/training/optimisers/#Optimiser-Reference